# How to set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to true

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I'm using 32 bit ubuntu 14.04. I have installed android emulator 2.0. I'm trying to run my app on emulator, but I'm not able to do so.

They say to "set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to true in your environment".

How can I do it?

Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the run configuration and in the extra command paste

> -force-32bit